# web.py running main twice, ignoring changes

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I have a simple web.py app that reads a config file and serves to URL paths. However I get two strange behaviors. One, changes made to data in the Main are not reflected in the results of GET. Two, Main appears to run twice.

Desired behavior is modifying data in Main will cause methods to see modified data, and not having main re-run.

Questions:

1. What is really happening here, that mydict is not modified in either
   GET.
2. Why am I getting some code running twice.
3. Simplest path to desired behavior (most important)
4. Pythonic path to desired behavior (least important)

*From pbuck (Accepted Answer): Answer for 3.) is replace*

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

*with:*

```
app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
```

Same behavior on pythons Linux (CentOS 6 python 2.6.6) and MacBook (brew python 2.7.12)

When started I get:

```
$ python ./foo.py 8080
Initializing mydict
Modifying mydict
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

When queried with:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/node/first/foo
wget http://localhost:8080/node/second/bar
```

Which results in (notice a second "Initializing mydict"):

```
Initializing mydict
firstClass.GET called with clobber foo
firstClass.GET somevalue is something static
127.0.0.1:52480 - - [17/Feb/2017 17:30:42] "HTTP/1.1 GET /node/first/foo" - 200 OK
secondClass.GET called with clobber bar
secondClass.GET somevalue is something static
127.0.0.1:52486 - - [17/Feb/2017 17:30:47] "HTTP/1.1 GET /node/second/bar" - 200 OK
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web

urls = (
    '/node/first/(.*)', 'firstClass',
    '/node/second/(.*)', 'secondClass'
    )

# Initialize web server, start it later at "app . run ()"
#app = web.application(urls, globals())
# Running web.application in Main or above does not change behavior

# Static Initialize mydict
print "Initializing mydict"
mydict = {}
mydict['somevalue'] = "something static"

class firstClass:
    def GET(self, globarg):
        print "firstClass.GET called with clobber %s" % globarg
        print "firstClass.GET somevalue is %s" % mydict['somevalue']
        return mydict['somevalue']

class secondClass:
    def GET(self, globarg):
        print "secondClass.GET called with clobber %s" % globarg
        print "secondClass.GET somevalue is %s" % mydict['somevalue']
        return mydict['somevalue']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    # read configuration files for initializations here
    print "Modifying mydict"
    mydict['somevalue'] = "something dynamic"
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, avoid using globals as they don't do what you think they do. Especially when you eventually deploy this under nginx / apache where there will (likely) be multiple processes running.

Longer answer

> 2. Why am I getting some code running twice?

Code, global to app.py, is running twice because it runs once, as it normally does. The second time is within the `web.application(urls, globals())` call. Really, that call to `globals()` sets up module loading / re-loading. Part of that is re-loading all modules (including app.py). If you set `autoreload=False` in the web.applications() call, it won't do that.

> 1. What is really happening here, that mydict is not modified in either GET?

mydict is getting set to 'something dynamic', but then being re-set to 'something static' on second load. Again, set `autoreload=False` and it will work as you expect.

> 3. Shortest path?

`autoreload=False`

> 4. Pythonic path?

.... well, I wonder why you have `mydict['somevalue'] = 'something static'` **and** `mydict['somevalue'] = 'something dynamic'` in your module this way: why not just set it once under `'__main__'`?

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. 1.  It's not nginx or apache, and will never be, it's a small/important 1 source module low impact service, thus globals. When I saw two of everything I immediately thought "fork", but no, but maybe it has a second thread. . There's no second process, I checked. 2. My understanding is the IF statement around main is supposed to prevent it from running twice.  3. I'll try that.  4. mydict['somevalue'] was set twice in the example only to better illustrate the problem. Originally I set it once in Main and it reverted to NoneType/None.

Comment: I found this thread, which seems to be the answer to the "correct" way to pass data safely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683968/arguments-to-web-py-handler-classes The only problem... even if I use this, I suspect the initialization code will still run twice!

Comment: BTW if the default behavior of web.py is to run __main__ twice, I consider that pathologically wrong.

Comment: The second time `app.py` is loaded, `__name__` is set to `__app__`, not `__main__`, so that's one way to have something happen, or not, on the first or second loading.

Comment: autoreload=False works great. Fixed both issues, running twice and resetting values. Will look into web.config Storage object to replace globals next.

Comment: A note to implementers: __autoreload=False__ setting fixed the issue of \_\_main\_\_ getting called twice, but the GET Class's \_\_init\_\_ still gets called on each GET method invocation. However putting data into __web.config.<whatever>__ instead of self.<attribute> addresses that problem, I was able to set an initState flag there, and other initialized data.