# where to open and close file in web.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py

A data file was getting corrupted when I terminated the program and realised that it was never properly closed.

It is quite critical that it does not get corrupted. So I added a statement to close the file.

Now, it seems like the file gets opened twice and then closed. That's one operation too many. There are of course many read-write operations in-between but it should only open and close the files once.

Here is what I have done to the standarize [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) template:

```
import web
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('data_file.h5')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__df = store['df']
    def GET(self):
        # several read-write, and modify operations on self.__df
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()
    finally:
        store.close()
```

Now, if I move the line which opens the store down inside the `try` statement at the bottom, it complains since it compiles the class but I can't find the variable `store`.

I tried initialising `store` with `None` at the top but it didn't work either. Then I tried putting that line up at the top in the function and calling it from the bottom, however, that didn't bring it into scope.

I was thinking of making it a `global` variable, which would probably do the trick, is that the right approach?

Comment: How does it seem to be "opened twice"? I'm not aware of any counter which would count the number of file "openings". It's open or not. As soon you close it once, it's closed.

Comment: If I put a print statement under the open line, it prints twice, although there are definitely many read-writes between the 2 opens and one close.

Comment: Do you mean that some code lines are executed twice and not that the file is opend twice? These are different things!

Comment: Well either way, would probably be better if that line were executed only once, it might otherwise create unnecessary wear and tear on the file, and don't want it corrupting..

Comment: supply the path to the class and let it open/close it? Supply the filehandle to the class and let it not close it?

Comment: I think closing it belongs in `finally` in case someone terminates the program so it closes correctly. The thing is, the class seems to reinitialize every time a request goes through the server it creates at `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` although the bit at the bottom under `if __name__ == "__main__"` of course only runs once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [web.py running twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305098/web-py-running-main-twice-ignoring-changes). As mentioned there, avoid using globals as they don't do what you think they do... app.py runs twice, once on startup and a second time within `web.appplication(urls, globals())`. If you set `autoreload=False` in web.applications() call, it won't load the file twice.

Another solution is to attach your `store` to `web.config`, which is globally available.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        web.config.store = pd.HDFStore('data_file.h5')
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()
    finally:
        web.config.store.close()
```

...and reference that global in your `__init__`

```
class index:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__df = web.config.store['df']
```